# false value is not getting equaled in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am using the below code to compare element out of `aria-checked="false"`.

```
expect((accessPolicyPage.listSelectAll).getAttribute("aria-checked")).toEqual("false");
```

Output is as `Expected [ 'false' ] to equal 'false'`.

I have tried with `toBeFalsy()` also.

Comment: This should probably be tagged javascript instead of java. Is it possible you are getting an array with single value ('false')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the answer for above question.

```
expect((accessPolicyPage.listSelectAll).get(0).getAttribute("aria-checked")).toEqual("false");
```

This will take the exact value from the array.

Thanks to Arseni for providing clue to find the answer.

Comment: By the way, instead of `.get(0)` you can use a more readable `.first()`.

Answer (score 1):

`accessPolicyPage.listSelectAll` returns you a list of elements. Because you have only one element it is returning array with one element. So that's why is says `Expected [ 'false' ] to equal 'false'`.

To check this you have to either loop through returned elements like this and check each element's attribute `aria-checked` like this:

```
var elements = accessPolicyPage.listSelectAll;
elements.forEach(function(singleElement) {
    expect(singleElement.getAttribute("aria-checked")).toEqual("false");
});
```

or just do it like so:

```
expect((accessPolicyPage.listSelectAll).getAttribute("aria-checked")[0]).toEqual("false");
```

Try it please and if it doesn't help, write a comment. I'll try to provide more help